# Wildcard for numbers with SQL

Tags: sql, sas, wildcard

I cant seem to find a correct answer for this. Everyone suggests using the where XX like '123%' but this doesnt work if the variable is numeric.

```
  select count (studyid) as NumberPersons from &data
        where numericvariable=6820% and case=0;
```

I want the count function to count all values that start with 6820** (682002, 682004, etc etc).

Comment: how about `where numericvariable / 100 = 6820 `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is in SAS, you can't quite do what was otherwise suggested since all SAS variables are doubles.

Options:

```
where floor(numericvariable/100)=6820

where 682000 le numericvariable le 682100

where put(numericvariable,z6.) like '6820%'
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct. The best option (which also works best with my macro, is the third (switching to a char)... which is also proving to be a bit problematic - SAS doesnt seem to want to count properly.

Comment: Not sure what that means.  Are you having numeric precision issues (0.1+0.1+0.1 ne 0.3 type issues)?

Comment: Sorry, thats my fault. I was being vague. I converted my variable to a char variable, but now, for some reason, I just get '0' counts when I ran the sql select count procedure. (This is likely just a stupid mistake somewhere).

Comment: I cheated - I truncated the numeric variable to four digits and I got the answers I wanted. Thanks all.

Comment: @Rainmaker What do you mean by cheated?

Comment: I just meant I cheated by simply creating a new table with truncated numbers (4 digits as opposed to 6) which gave me the results I wanted, but feels like a 'short-cut' and not the 'proper' way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

As juergen d said in his comment:

```
select count(studyid) as NumberPersons from &data where numericvariable / 100 = 6820
```

will work. Other 10 based ranges are simply adding/removing 0s from the divisor. More complicated ranges could be done, but not as easily.

Comment: FYI, in [tag:sas] this won't work as presented because there's no `int` data type, all numbers are floating point (doubles, generally), so you don't get the automatic truncation like you do in other languages.

Comment: Deleted my ridiculous comment. Sorry for typing without thinking.

Comment: Happens to all of us :)